# How do I study for a basic linux competency test?

Tags: linux, unix, test

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux knowledge a Junior cannot miss](https://serverfault.com/questions/13597/linux-knowledge-a-junior-cannot-miss)

One of the requirements for a position I'm seeking includes some basic linux server administration. I've had some experience so I'm not too worried, but I wouldn't consider myself an expert. As far as I know the test will have 10 open-ended questions about basic linux administration.

How or what do I "study"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get yourself an LPIC 1 book, that's the closest you will get, I guess.

Comment: The Linux+ material might be good as well.  Though it tends to be more basic then LPIC.